# How to show AlertDialog only on click of "OK"button in my App?

Tags: android

I am using below Alert Dialog to show a message.

I want to show this Alert Dialog only when user clicks the "OK" button.

How can I do that ?

```
/* Show Warning Dialog begins */
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// Creates textview for centre title
myMsg = new TextView(this);
myMsg.setText("Hello");
myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
myMsg.setTextSize(20); 
myMsg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

//set custom title
builder.setCustomTitle(myMsg);
builder.setMessage("Hi!");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

//Create custom message
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
/* Show Warning Dialog ends */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this. You need to implement `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` interface for button.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    // do your stuff here
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add click Listener to your positive button like this:

```
/*Show Warning Dialog*/
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    // Creates textview for centre title
                      myMsg = new TextView(this);
                      myMsg.setText("Hello");
                      myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                      myMsg.setTextSize(20); 
                      myMsg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    //set custom title
                    builder.setCustomTitle(myMsg);
                    builder.setMessage("Hi!");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new                   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       // Execute your process
             }
            });  

              AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
                    //Create custom message
                    TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    /*Show Warning Dialog ends*/
```